# How do I select multiple TFS folders and combine under one eclipse java project

Tags: tfs, eclipse-plugin, team-explorer-everywhere

I have TFS folders segregated by release. Under a release folder, I have multiple folders for a Thick Client GUI code and other multiple folders for a Thin Client GUI code. I would like to import the set of Thick Client GUI folders into one eclipse java project and the other set of Thin Client GUI folders into another eclipse java project using Team Explorer Everywhere. If I import the release folder into the Thick Client GUI java project and then exclude the Thin Client GUI folders in the Java Project properties then because of a TFS restriction I cannot import the same release folder into the Thin Client GUI java project. But if I import the set of Thick Client GUI folders under the release folder into one eclipse project, Team Explorer Everywhere creates a java project for each folder. How can I select multiple TFS folders and have these combined under one eclipse java project under one src folder? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide some more details on the hierarchy of your TFS server?  It sounds like you want a java project for the common (shared) code and then two java projects, one for the thick client and another for the thin client?

Comment: I do not have shared code. What I have is the following hierarchy on the TFS server: 1st level: full project; 2nd Level: release number (e.g. 3.0) ...; 3rd levels: Thick Client Folder 1; Thin Client Folder 1; com.company.thickclient Folder; com.company.thinclient Folder; Thick Client Folder 2; Thick Client Folder 3 ...; Thin Client Folder 2 ...; I want to create a Thick Client Project from the thick client folders and a Thin Client Project for the thin client folders.